# Вы можете доступ

Tags: дефект, статус-воспроизведено, локализация, привилегии

[image]

Пасиб, что на «Вы», аж с большой буквы; но «вы можете доступ» — это слишком не по-русски даже для меня! 8)

Comment: All your privilege are belong to us.

Comment: Англоязычные программисты не могут в падежи.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Предлагаю такой вариант, подойдет к любой привилегии:

> Благодаря своим усилиям, вы получаете возможность:
>
> - Доступ к очереди проверки
> - Править общие сообщения
> - Общение в чатах
> - Защищенные вопросы
> - Проверенный участник

Как можно заметить, универсальную конструкцию достаточно сложно подобрать, т.к. наименования привилегий грамматически отличаются друг от друга.

---

Вопрос, что будет с версткой, если текст растянется на две строки? Подозреваю, что сломается, как обычно и происходит.

Comment: Мне кажется, нужно просто иметь различные формы описания привилегий. То, что на английском access to review queue можно употреблять в обоих контекстах, ещё не значит, что то же подойдёт и на русском. Думаю, стоит открыть баг в движке локализации.

Comment: @VladD: согласен, что было бы хорошо иметь несколько форм.

Comment: То есть по сути нужны формы в контексте именования (в описании) и прямого дополнения (в рассматриваемом случае).

Comment: @VladD: дополняйте, редактируйте ) [Несколько разных строк для объявления привилегий на личной странице пользователя](http://meta.ru.stackoverflow.com/q/1981)