# Несколько разных строк для объявления привилегий на личной странице пользователя

Tags: предложение, локализация, страница-учётной-записи, привилегии

Вызвано вопросом «[Вы можете доступ](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/1979/181472)».

Вот некоторые названия привилегий этого сайта:

> - Доступ к очереди проверки
> - Править общие сообщения
> - Общение в чатах
> - Защищенные вопросы
> - Проверенный участник

Названия привилегий сформулированы довольно-таки разными конструкциями и очень сложно придумать общую формулировку, которая звучала бы хорошо со всеми вариантами. Сейчас она в лучшем случае может быть хороша с несколькими, но на грани фола с несколькими другими.

> Благодаря своим усилиям, вы получаете возможность: править общие сообщения.
>   Благодаря своим усилиям, вы получаете возможность: проверенный участник.
>
> Благодаря вашим усилиям, вам доступно общение в чатах
>   Благодаря вашим усилиям, вам доступно защищенные вопросы
>
> Благодаря вашим усилиям, вы теперь проверенный участник.
>   Благодаря вашим усилиям, вы теперь защищенные вопросы.

Поэтому нужно внедрить в движок сайта несколько вариантов строк и предоставить возможность выбрать вариант для каждой привилегии индивидуально.

Comment: Мне кажется, имеет смысл сначала выяснить список _всех_ контекстов, в которых описания привилегий используются на сайте.

Comment: «Благодаря вашим усилиям, вам доступно общение в чатах» звучит немного издевательски.

Comment: @VladD: видимо, и первую половину фразы стоит переработать.

Comment: Нужно бы расширить на ["Инструменты модератора"](https://i.stack.imgur.com/s4XIK.png).

Answer (score 2):

Предлагаю такой список:

- Ваша репутация возросла, теперь у вас есть **доступ к очереди проверки**.
- Ваша репутация возросла, теперь вы можете **править общие сообщения**.
- Ваша репутация возросла, теперь вам доступно **общение в чатах**.
- Ваша репутация возросла, теперь вы можете **защищать вопросы**.
- Ваша репутация возросла, теперь вы — **проверенный участник**.

Comment: Получилось четыре варианта.